# How to call dynamic controller function from a same endpoint of a route in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, express

Lets say I have a single route endpoint, and I am passing a parameter through header or url. Based on header/url parameter the route controller will call dynamically.

**Example: If I'm passing through header { item: 'A' } or { item: 'B' }.
So based on the header value like: A or B, the controller will call dynamically. Here middleware can check the header information and make the controller function call as per. But I don't know how do I do that!**

Now:

```
app.get('/my-home', middleware.isHome, my_home.getMyHomeData);
```

Want to route like:

```
app.get('/my-home', middleware.isHome, A_home.getMyHomeData);
```

or

```
app.get('/my-home', middleware.isHome, B_home.getMyHomeData);
```

here the dynamic controller name A_home or B_home will based on header value A or B.

I can check the header information into the controller function and will make the decision as per. But I want to make it into the route.

Answer (score -1):

I made and tested a quick dummy express app with a possible solution - using [`res.redirect()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect)

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express()

app.use((req,res,next) => {
    if(req.path === "/my-home" && req.headers['item']){
        res.redirect(`/my-home/use-item-handler/${req.headers['item']}`)
    }

    next()
})


const handler1 = (req,res,next) => {
    res.json({
        item: "h1" 
    })
}

const handler2 = (req,res,next) => {
    res.json({
        item: "h2" 
    })
}

app.use("/my-home/use-item-handler/h1",handler1);
app.use("/my-home/use-item-handler/h2",handler2);


app.listen(3010,() => {
    console.log("LISTENING");
})
```

In the above app, if you pass the value `h1` in the header `item`, `handler1` will be used and for `h2`, `handler2` will be used, both at the path `http://your.url.com/my-home`.

You will need this header-based functionality on some base path (in your case "/,my-home") and you can add a middleware at that path which checks for the header value, and redirects the request on the same server to a different path which uses your desired handler. Here `handler1` and `handler2` are analogous to your `A_home.getMyHomeData` and `B_home.getMyHomeData`, where instead of having to load the handler, we can have them at a path to which we can redirect the request useing the middleware.

### Possible approach:

Let's define the paths for the requests in a `constants.js` file in the `lib` directory of the project. This is of course not necessary but we may have to use the paths in different files in our project, so saving them in one constants file will help us change the paths more easily if ever required.

**/lib/constants.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    "HOME_BASE_PATH": "/my-home",
    "ITEMS_PATH": "/use-item-handler"
}
```

Then we can have a home controller (I'm assuming you're using MVC pattern since it's very common) which will conatain our base path at `/my-home` and the necessary routes for the various items.

**/controllers/home.js**

```js
const homeRouter = require('express').Router();
const { 
    HOME_BASE_PATH,
    ITEMS_PATH
} = require('../lib/constants.js');

const ITEM_REQUEST_HANDLERS = {
    "A": {
        getMyHomeData: (req,res,next) => {
            res.json({
                item: "A",
                data: "1234" 
            })
        }
    },
    "B": {
        getMyHomeData: (req,res,next) => {
            res.json({
                item: "B",
                data: "5678" 
            })
        }
    }
}

const redirectByItemHeader = (req,res,next) => {
    if(req.headers['item'] && ITEM_REQUEST_HANDLERS[req.headers['item']]){
        return res.redirect(`${HOME_BASE_PATH}${ITEMS_PATH}/${req.headers['item']}`)
    }
    next();
}

homeRouter.get(`/`,redirectByItemHeader,(req,res,next) => {
    res.json({
        item: "NO ITEM",
        data: "DEFAULT"
    })
})

//set route for each item
Object.keys(ITEM_REQUEST_HANDLERS).forEach(item => {
    homeRouter.get(`${ITEMS_PATH}/${item}`,ITEM_REQUEST_HANDLERS[item].getMyHomeData);
})

module.exports = homeRouter;
```

How we are fetching the handlers is via an object `ITEM_REQUEST_HANDLERS` (you may have this in a different file if needed), in which the key will be the `item` passed in the request header and the value will be an object (analogous to `A_home` or `B_home` in your question) containing the handler (`.getMyHomeData()`), which we can bind to a given path (`/my-home/use-item-handler/:your-item`).

**NOTE:** Technically, we are not binding the handler at runtime to *one* path, but we are binding *all* the necessary handlers to certain pre-defined paths at server start, and then dynamically redirecting the requests to them depending upon the `item` header at runtime.

An **alternate approach** to the home controller could be that you could take the `item` value as a url param in which case you will have to call the handler for that item as a function within the request handler of that route. The part there we set the route for each item will change as follows:

```
homeRouter.get(`${ITEMS_PATH}/:item`,(req,res,next) => {
    //fetch the object that contains handler for that item, call as a function
    ITEM_REQUEST_HANDLERS[req.params.item].getMyHomeData(req,res,next);
})
```

Then your entry file for the express app can contain the following:

**app.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const homeController = require('./controllers/home.js'); 
const {
    HOME_BASE_PATH
} = require('./lib/constants.js')

const app = express()


app.use(HOME_BASE_PATH,homeController);


app.listen(3010,() => {
    console.log("LISTENING");
})
```

You can actually copy this code and make this small dummy app to see exatly how it works.

### Adding/Removing a Handler for an Item

This would be as simple as adding another entry in the `ITEM_REQUEST_HANDLERS` object, with the key being the new value of an item (say, item "C") and the values being an object containing an implementaion of the handler in `.getMyHomeData()`, or by simply removing the entry. Of course, you'll have to make the changes and restart the server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for your response, appreciated!  Is there any other way that I can dynamically bind the controller name ?

Answer (score -1):

Create a class called dynamic controller class. create a setter, getter and two private   method(A, B). invoke class before route declaration. In the middleware, set the value of item inside the class. and in route callback use the getter method. Inside getter method use switch case to call dynamic controller methods(A/B) based on item header input !

Comment: Would you share an example link @darkie8

Comment: @AmitNayek go to this part. if ur node version supports class , use directly the class or just use the babel transpiled version https://es6console.com/khcf8opl/